# Xamarin Forms: Push notification is not receiving to ios device

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have done the following things:

1. Created a project in FCM console and added ios project into it.
2. Downloaded the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and added it to the xamarin forms ios project directory and set the build action as `Bundlesource`.
3. On Info.plist enabled remote notification background mode.
4. Added FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled in the app’s Info.plist file and set it to No.
5. Created a provisioning profile and distribution certificate and installed it into the keychain access. Also, mapped these certificates in the project options.
6. Uploaded .p12 certificate in FCM console.
7. Added codes for handling push notification in `AppDelegate.cs`.

**My Code:**

```
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App("",""));
            RequestPushPermissionsAsync();
            _launchoptions = options;
            // Register your app for remote notifications.
        if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
        {
            // iOS 10 or later
            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                Console.WriteLine(granted);
            });

            // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            // For iOS 10 data message (sent via FCM)
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.RemoteMessageDelegate = this;
        }
        else
        {
            // iOS 9 or before
            var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
            var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, null);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
        }

        UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
        NSDictionary _launchoptions;
        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
            if (_launchoptions != null && _launchoptions.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
            {
                var notfication = _launchoptions[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;
                PresentNotification(notfication);
            }
            _launchoptions = null;
        }

        async Task RequestPushPermissionsAsync()
        {
            var requestResult = await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorizationAsync(
                 UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert
                | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge
                | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound);

            bool approved = requestResult.Item1;
            NSError error = requestResult.Item2;
            if (error == null)
            {
                if (!approved)
                {
                    Console.Write("Permission to receive notification was not granted");
                    return;
                }

                var currentSettings = await UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.GetNotificationSettingsAsync();
                if (currentSettings.AuthorizationStatus != UNAuthorizationStatus.Authorized)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Permissions were requested in the past but have been revoked (-Settings  app)");
                    return;
                }
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write($"Error requesting permissions: {error}.");
            }
        }

        public async override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(
        UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        //if (deviceToken == null)
        //{
        //    // Can happen in rare conditions e.g. after restoring a device.
        //    return;
        //}

        //Console.WriteLine($"Token received: {deviceToken}");

        // Get current device token
        var DeviceToken = deviceToken.Description;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(DeviceToken))
        {
            DeviceToken = DeviceToken.Trim('<').Trim('>');
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"deviceToken received: {deviceToken}");
        Console.WriteLine($"DeviceToken received: {DeviceToken}");

        // Get previous device token
        var oldDeviceToken = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.StringForKey("PushDeviceToken");

        // Has the token changed?
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(oldDeviceToken) || !oldDeviceToken.Equals(DeviceToken))
        {
            //TODO: Put your own logic here to notify your server that the device token has changed/been created!
        }

        // Save new device token
        NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetString(DeviceToken, "PushDeviceToken");

        await SendRegistrationToServerAsync(DeviceToken);
    }

        async Task SendRegistrationTokenToMainPRoject(NSData deviceToken)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, "fcmtoken", deviceToken.ToString());
        }

        public override void FailedToRegisterForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSError error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Failed to register for remote notifications: {error.Description}");
        }

        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo,
            Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            PresentNotification(userInfo);
            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
            try
            {
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
                NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;
                var message = (aps[new NSString("webContentList")] as NSString).ToString();
                LoadApplication(new App("", message));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //LogInfo.ReportErrorInfo(ex.Message, ex.StackTrace, "AppDelegate-DidReceiveRemoteNotification");
            }
        }

        void PresentNotification(NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            NSDictionary aps = userInfo.ObjectForKey(new NSString("aps")) as NSDictionary;

            var msg = string.Empty;

            if (aps.ContainsKey(new NSString("alert")))
            {
                msg = (aps[new NSString("alert")] as NSString).ToString();
            }
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(msg))
            {
                msg = "(unable to parse)";
            }
            MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, App.NotificationReceivedKey, msg);
        }
    }
```

I am not using any NuGet packages in ios part. When running the project into a device, the FCM token generating part is working and I can see the fcm token on the VS console. I tried to send a test notification to a device from postman but getting `InvalidRegistration` error.

**Postman Response**

```
{
    "multicast_id": 8754155136812875313,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidRegistration"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Postman Body**

```
 {
    "to" : "d20ad003 7473bfba 85dffc33 1534decf b4b886f1 c738878f fd7f2c60 d9dabc36",
 "collapse_key" : "type_a",
 "data" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification in Data",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification in Title",
     "key_1" : "Value for key_1",
     "key_2" : "Value for key_2"
 },
 "notification" : {
     "body" : "Body of Your Notification",
     "title": "Title of Your Notification",
     "sound": "default",
     "content_available" : true
 }
}
```

I have completed the android part implementation and notifications are receiving when push from the postman. But getting `InvalidRegistration` error on ios part and not receiving any notification in my ios device.

I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM&t=3230s) youtube video for this implementation and the complete source code is [here](https://github.com/Krumelur/XamUAzureNotificationHub).

Anyone suggest a solution for this issue.

Thanks in advance.

**Update**

I have created a sample project and a postman collection and added it to my [google folder](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GWbjWHfSfx7j3_KH11wqauMiw7Y-07AY).

Postman collection contains 2 REST APIs, one for Android device and the other one for ios device

If you import the postman collection and run the Android REST API, I will receive the notification, because I have added my device FCM token on it. But when running the ios REST API in postman will return `InvalidRegistration` error in postman.

Please go through the sample project and please give me a solution?

Comment: I don't use  FCM before but I wonder if you have to do any initialization for firebase in AppDelegate.cs? Something like this:[FCM.iOS](https://github.com/HabibAli/FCM-Xamarin-Forms/blob/master/FCM/FCM/FCM.iOS/AppDelegate.cs)

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I follow [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=le2lDY22xwM&t=3230s "this") youtube video for this implementation and the complete source code is [here](https://github.com/Krumelur/XamUAzureNotificationHub "here").

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am not using any nuget packages in ios part and in the video he is don't telling about the initialization for firebase.https://github.com/Krumelur/XamUAzureNotificationHub/blob/master/XamUNotif/XamUNotif.iOS/AppDelegate.cs

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have updated the question with a sample project, can you please have a look?

Comment: Ok, I will have a look.

Comment: After watching the video, I think you are using the Azure Push Notification Hub to push notifications, right? If so, FCM has nothing to do with the iOS notification. FCM is use to push notification to Android device. So, if you get the InvalidRegistration there, that means `GCM Bad Channel Error`.(look at this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/metrics-supported) and search for InvalidRegistration) Check the devicetoken and settings in the Azure.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am not using Azure to push notifications. I just follow that video for the implementation. Is FCM only for Android devices?  It is possible to push notification to ios device using FCM, right?

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I am using FCM for push notification to my android devices and ios devices. I added all the steps that I follow in the question, FCM token is generating when running on real iPhone device. I am using postman for testing the notification. For the Android device, the notifications are receiving. But getting InvalidRegistration error for pushing notification to ios device. I have added sample project and sample postman collection link in the question.

Comment: I know you are using FCM for push notification to your android devices and ios devices. While in the video, in iOS part, the author is not using FCM to push the notifications to iOS device. I searched the Internet and can not find a document about how to implement FCM on xamarin.iOS. You can follow this two articles to achieve that: [cloud-messaging/ios](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)  and [Firebase.CloudMessaging/component/GettingStarted](https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/component/GettingStarted.md).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I will go through this and update you, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reviewed and can resolve this issue.

1. Install the plugin Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.CloudMessaging in iOS project.
2. AppDelegate class needs to inherit from IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate and IMessagingDelegate interfaces.
3. Include the Firebase.Core.App.Configure (); in FinishedLaunching method before registering remote notification.
4. Then you can add the registering remote notification code (You can get the code from given link).
5. You need to set user notification delegate and messaging shared instant delegate (UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this; // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS) and Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;).
6. Include DidReceiveRegistrationToken and DidReceiveMessage methods with corresponding attributes

Please refer this AppDelegate class for more clarity https://github.com/xamarin/GoogleApisForiOSComponents/blob/master/Firebase.CloudMessaging/samples/CloudMessagingSample/CloudMessagingSample/AppDelegate.cs

Related Xamarin Forums thread
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/159477/xamarin-forms-push-notification-is-not-receiving-to-ios-device#latest