# Xamarin.Forms IOS not showing FCM push notification on IOS physical device

Tags: ios, firebase, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, firebase-cloud-messaging

1.I created project in firebase console.

2.Created certificate for push notification on the Apple account

3.Added GoogleService-info.plist , as a BundleResource

4. Allow to use Push Notifications in Entitlements.plist
5. Allow Enable Backgroud Modes and Remote notifications in Info.plist

**This is my code in AppDelegate**

```
  [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate, IUNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, IMessagingDelegate
    {
        //
        // This method is invoked when the application has loaded and is ready to run. In this 
        // method you should instantiate the window, load the UI into it and then make the window
        // visible.
        //
        // You have 17 seconds to return from this method, or iOS will terminate your application.
        //
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            // We have checked to see if the device is running iOS 8, if so we are required to ask for the user's permission to receive notifications    

            // check for a notification    
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
            {
                var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, null
                );

                app.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings);
            }
           if (options != null){    
                if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey)){    
                    UILocalNotification localNotification = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as UILocalNotification;    
                    if (localNotification != null){
                        var okCancelAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(localNotification.AlertAction, localNotification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                        okCancelAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, alert => Console.WriteLine("Okay was clicked")));
                        // reset our badge    
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController.PresentViewController(okCancelAlertController, true, null);
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;    
                    }    
                }    
            }
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = Color.White.ToUIColor();
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.TitleTextAttributes = new UIStringAttributes { ForegroundColor = UIColor.White };
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle(UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
            Forms.SetFlags("SwipeView_Experimental");
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init();
            Firebase.Core.App.Configure();
            Messaging.SharedInstance.Delegate = this;

            LoadApplication(new App());
            // Register your app for remote notifications.
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(10, 0))
            {

                // For iOS 10 display notification (sent via APNS)
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

                var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
                UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(granted);
                });
            }
            else
            {
                // iOS 9 or before
                var allNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound;
                var settings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(allNotificationTypes, new NSSet());
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(settings);
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            }
            var token = Messaging.SharedInstance.FcmToken ?? "";
            Console.WriteLine($"FCM token: {token}");
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
        //Receive Local Notifications
        public override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
        {

            UIAlertController okayAlertController = UIAlertController.Create(notification.AlertAction, notification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okayAlertController.AddAction(UIAlertAction.Create("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
        public override void OnActivated(UIApplication uiApplication)
        {
 
            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(13, 0))
            {
                // If VS has updated to the latest version , you can use StatusBarManager , else use the first line code
                // UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.StatusBarFrame);
                UIView statusBar = new UIView(UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.WindowScene.StatusBarManager.StatusBarFrame);
                statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor(); 
                statusBar.TintColor= Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();    
                
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.AddSubview(statusBar);
            }
            else
            {
                UIView statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
                if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
                {
                    statusBar.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor(); 
                    statusBar.TintColor= Color.FromHex("07987f").ToUIColor();
                }
            }
            base.OnActivated(uiApplication);
        }
        [Export("messaging:didReceiveRegistrationToken:")]
        public void DidReceiveRegistrationToken(Messaging messaging, string fcmToken)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Firebase registration token: {fcmToken}");

            // TODO: If necessary send token to application server.
            // Note: This callback is fired at each app startup and whenever a new token is generated.
        }
        public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
        {

            Messaging.SharedInstance.ApnsToken = deviceToken;
        }
        public override void ReceivedRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
            // TODO: Handle data of notification

            // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

            // Print full message.
            Console.WriteLine(userInfo);
        }
        public override void DidReceiveRemoteNotification(UIApplication application, NSDictionary userInfo, Action<UIBackgroundFetchResult> completionHandler)
        {
            // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
            // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
            // TODO: Handle data of notification

            // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

            // Print full message.
            Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
        }
        // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
        // Handle incoming notification messages while app is in the foreground.
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void WillPresentNotification(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotification notification, Action<UNNotificationPresentationOptions> completionHandler)
        {
            var userInfo = notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

            // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
            //Messaging.SharedInstance.AppDidReceiveMessage (userInfo);

            // Print full message.
            Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            // Change this to your preferred presentation option
            completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.Alert);
        }
        // Handle notification messages after display notification is tapped by the user.
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
        public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, Action completionHandler)
        {
            var userInfo = response.Notification.Request.Content.UserInfo;

            // Print full message.
            Console.WriteLine(userInfo);

            completionHandler();
        }
    }
```

Stuck with this one week. I don't know what to do next to work. Any suggestion? I copy fcmToken from the app and paste in the Firebase console for Test Message.

Comment: You could refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56881510/10768653) to see if the steps are correct

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT i checked but i can't find anything